Centering Text in Assembly Language Programming
Do you have any idea on how I can center the text or string in Assembly Language Programming?
Here's my source code:
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
;**********************************************
    labelmenu db 0ah,0dh,"MAIN MENU $"
    labelcal db 0ah,0dh,0ah,0dh,"[1] CALCULATOR $"
    labelconv db 0ah,0dh,"[2] CONVERSION $"
    labelext db 0ah,0dh,"[3] EXIT $"
.code
main proc
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax
;MAIN MENU
;**********************************************
displaymenu:
    call centerclear
    mov ah,09h
    lea dx,labelmenu  ;MAIN MENU LABEL
    int 21h
    lea dx,labelcal   ;[1]CALCULATOR LABEL
    int 21h
    lea dx,labelconv  ;[2]CONVERSION LABEL
    int 21h
    lea dx,labelext   ;[3]EXIT LABEL
    int 21h

I have tried the solution below, but it does not work for me:
mov ah,3    ; Get the current cursor position
mov bh,0
int 10h

mov ah,2    ; Set cursor position
mov bh,0
mov dl,39   ; New column. In an 80-column text mode this will just about center
            ; the 3 characters 
            ; We want to stay on the same row, so we don't change DH
int 10h


You can't reliably mix int 10h BIOS screen display functions with int 21h DOS standard output (which basically emulates a teletypewriter).  If you want text positioning or any other kind of TUI stuff, you probably want to use int 10h exclusively.

Your first try is going in the right direction. All you still need is taking into account the length of the text that you want to center across the screen. The calculation that is required is:
Column = (WidthOfScreen - NumberOfCharacters) / 2

I have used next modified data definitions:
labelmenu db "MAIN MENU", 13, 10, 10, "$"
labelcal  db "[1] CALCULATOR", 13, 10, "$"
labelconv db "[2] CONVERSION", 13, 10, "$"
labelext  db "[3] EXIT      ", 13, 10, "$"
                      ^^^^^^
                      space-padding

The trick for a nice menu is to display the list of choices left-aligned. Therefore I used space-padding so all these texts can share the same length.
Please note that the length must not include the carriage return, linefeed, nor $-terminator.
  mov  dx, offset labelmenu
  mov  si, 9
  call PrintCentered

  mov  si, 14
  mov  dx, offset labelcal
  call PrintCentered
  mov  dx, offset labelconv
  call PrintCentered
  mov  dx, offset labelext
  call PrintCentered
  
  ...
  
; IN (ds:dx,si) OUT () MOD (ax,bh,cx,dx)
PrintCentered:
  push dx         ; (1)
  mov  bh, 0
  mov  ah, 03h    ; BIOS.GetCursor
  int  10h        ; -> CX DX

  mov  ax, 80     ; (ScreenWidth - NumberOfCharacters) / 2
  sub  ax, si
  shr  ax, 1
  mov  dl, al     ; Set Column, but keep Row

  mov  ah, 02h    ; BIOS.SetCursor
  int  10h

  pop  dx         ; (1)
  mov  ah, 09h    ; DOS.DisplayString
  int  21h        ; -> AL="$"
  ret

